# Show that $ \Vert Tx_\varepsilon -x_\varepsilon \Vert \leq \varepsilon $

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

**Exercise:**

> Let $X$ be a Banach space, $\Vert \quad \Vert$ is a norm on $X$. Let $B_1= \{ x \in X:\Vert x \Vert=1 \} $. If the oprator $T: B_1\rightarrow B_1$ satisfies for all $x, y\in B_1$, there is $\Vert Tx-Ty\Vert \leq \Vert x-y\Vert$. Then for all $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$, there exists $x_\varepsilon\in B_1$ such as $\Vert Tx_\varepsilon-x_\varepsilon \Vert\leq \varepsilon$.

**My Attempt:**

This exercise looks quite like the Fixed Point Theorem so I want to prove it by the similar way. But I failed because without $0< \theta< 1$ in the Fixed Point Theorem I can't find a Cauchy sequence. So I can't find a $x$ even is dependent on $\varepsilon$ to make $Tx$ and $x$ close enough. I'm not sure if my attempt is on a correct way.

**Update:**

According to @Brian-Moehring, there is a mistake in this exercise.

Maybe the $B_1$ should be a unit ball rather than a unit sphere.

Comment: Is $T$ a linear operator $X\to X$ such that $T(B_1)\subseteq B_1$, or just a map $B_1\to B_1$?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Sorry that's a clerical error. It should be $B_1$.

Comment: @AnneBauval $T$ is just a map $B_1\rightarrow B_1$, and we don't know if it's linear.

Comment: Something seems to be missing.  As of right now, we could set $Tx = -x$ and then $Tx$ is always as far as possible from $x$.  Perhaps some equality should be an inequality?  ... or perhaps some inequality should be strict or (even better) utilize some constant $C < 1$?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc My proposal to the effect of $0< C < 1$ is $\|Tx-Ty\| \leq C\|x-y\|$, which no fixed rotation would satisfy for any $0< C < 1$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I check the exercise again and I'm sure nothing is missing here. But I'm not sure if there is any mistake in the exercise.

Comment: There *is* a mistake in the exercise, since a counterexample (already ireported by Brian) is $T(x)=-x$. I suspect $B_1$ should be the (closed?) unit ball, not the sphere.

Comment: @AnneBauval Very convincing. I'll figure it out.

Answer (score 5):

I think $B_1$ stands for the unit ball instead of the unit sphere. In that case, consider $Ux = \frac12 Tx + \frac12 (1- \epsilon)x$. You can easily prove that the map is a contraction map and so you can find a fixed point $x_\epsilon$. $$Ux_\epsilon = x_\epsilon \implies Tx_\epsilon - x_\epsilon = \frac\epsilon2 x_\epsilon \implies \left\|Tx_\epsilon - x_\epsilon \right\|\le \frac\epsilon2  < \epsilon$$

Answer (score 2):

In fact, if $B_1$ is a unit ball rather than a unit sphere, I can give a proof.

For all $r$ that $0<r<1$, it's clear that $rT$ is a contraction mapping from $B_1$ to $B_1$. So there is a fixed point $y$ for $rT$ such that $rT(y)=y$. Then we have
$$\Vert T(y)-y\Vert =\Vert T(y)-rT(y) \Vert=(1-r)\Vert T(y) \Vert \le 1-r.$$
So given $\varepsilon$, let $r$ close enough to 1, we have $\Vert T(y_\varepsilon)-y_\varepsilon\Vert \le 1-r\le \varepsilon$. Here $y_\varepsilon$ is the fixed point of $rT$.